# Is there a more accurate solver than uniroot to solve a non-linear equation?

Tags: r, solver

My problem is that I use uniroot to solve for a value of a non-linear function but the problem is that the values are not as expected when I calculate them by hand.

I wrote a function like:

```html
yield.to.call <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){
  #d <- (1+(ytc/f))^f
  c <- c/f 
  if(t<92){t <- ((92-t)/(92-0))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+13))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+14))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+15))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+16))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+17))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+18))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+19))-p}}
  else if(t<184){t <- ((184-t)/(184-92))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+13))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+14))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+15))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+16))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+17))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+18))-p}}
  else if(t<275){t <- ((275-t)/(275-184))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+13))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+14))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+15))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+16))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+17))-p}}
  else if(t<365){t <- ((365-t)/(365-275))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+13))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+14))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+15))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+16))-p}}
  else if(t<457){t <- ((457-t)/(457-365))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+13))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+14))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+15))-p}}
  else if(t<548){t <- ((548-t)/(548-457))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+13))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+14))-p}}
  else if(t<639){t <- ((639-t)/(639-548))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+13))-p}}
  else if(t<730){t <- ((730-t)/(730-639))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+12))-p}}
  else if(t<821){t <- ((821-t)/(821-730))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+11))-p}}
  else if(t<915){t <- ((915-t)/(915-821))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+10))-p}}
  else if(t<1006){t <- ((1006-t)/(1006-915))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+9))-p}}
  else if(t<1097){t <- ((1097-t)/(1097-1006))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+8))-p}}
  else if(t<1188){t <- ((1188-t)/(1188-1097))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+7))-p}}
  else if(t<1280){t <- ((1280-t)/(1280-1188))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+6))-p}}
  else if(t<1371){t <- ((1371-t)/(1371-1280))#done 
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+5))-p}}
  else if(t<1461){t <- ((1461-t)/(1461-1371))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+4))-p}}
  else if(t<1553){t <- ((1553-t)/(1553-1461)) 
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+3))-p}}
  else if(t<1645){t <- ((1645-t)/(1645-1553))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))+(c+N)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+2))-p}}
  else if(t<1736){t <- ((1736-t)/(1736-1645))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){c/((1+(ytc/f))^(t))+(N+c)/((1+(ytc/f))^(t+1))-p}}
  else if(t<1826){t<-((1826-t)/(1826-1736))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){(N+c)/(1+(ytc/f)^(t))-p}}
  else q <- function(ytc,p,c,t=0,f=4,N=100){(N+c)/p-(ytc/f)-1} 
  
  q2<- function(ytc){q(ytc,p,c,t,N=100)}
  yield.t.c <- uniroot(q2,c(0,1),tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5)$root 
  return(yield.t.c)
}

yield.to.call(ytc,p=100,t=1790,c=5,N=100)
```

For example the value for t=1790 is 6.987728e-05 but should be like 0.0126 or so.

Yield to call is a function that should calculate for me the internal rate of return of the cash flow a a coupon bond. Meaning a cash flow of the structure y=c/(1+(r/4))^t where everything is known except for r which I try to solve for.

Has anyone an idea?

EDIT: I found out that the problem lies within the line:

```
else if(t<1826){t<-((1826-t)/(1826-1736))
    q <- function(ytc,p,c,t,f=4,N=100){(N+c)/(1+(ytc/f)^(t))-p}}
```

As the function is not linear for any t value anymore:

[Plot of t=1790](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvyPf.png)

Any idea how to "linearized" it and getting my desired solution?

Comment: Does maybe someone have an idea with using optimize or so?

Comment: The matter is now only to make my function linear for every t[1736,1825] and I am done   Please help!

Comment: Check your parentheses placement, it looks like you are adding 1 to (ytc/f)^t.  I believe it should be `(N+c)/(1+(ytc/f))^(t)-p` and this generates a root of 0.126

Comment: That was it!!! I am so happy now!!! THANK YOU! You saved my day and my bachelor thesis! @Dave2e

Comment: Glad to help!  Good luck finishing up.